# Table view not appending Table view cell

Tags: ios, swift

I am building this calender app that tracks the user's events. On the dashboard page once the user presses the big orange button there should be a new table view cell appended and the user will be able to edit the event. But when I try out the plus button nothing happens. Can someone help me??
Thanks!!

Here is my code

Dashboard ViewController----------------------------------------------

```
//
//  DashboardViewController.swift
//  Pursuit 1.0
//
//  Created by Ryan Du on 9/9/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Ryan Du. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController, cellInfoDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return events.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let Dcells = events[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DashboardCell") as! DashboardCell

    cell.setDashboardCell(cell: Dcells)

    return cell
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1

}


func tableCellInfo(title: String?, description: String?) {
}



@IBOutlet weak var DashboardAdd: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func DashboardAddA(_ sender: Any) {

events.append(Dashboard(title: "Untitled", description: "Add A Description Here"))
    tableView.register(DashboardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DashboardCell")

}


var events: [Dashboard] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


    }





func createArray(titleOfEvent: String, descriptionOfEvent: String) -> [Dashboard] {

    var Events: [Dashboard] = []
    let event = Dashboard(title: titleOfEvent, description: descriptionOfEvent)
    Events.append(event)

    return Events


}



}
```

Dashboard Cell---------------------------------------------------------

```
//
//  DashboardCell.swift
//  Pursuit 1.0
//
//  Created by Ryan Du on 9/20/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Ryan Du. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

protocol cellInfoDelegate {
func tableCellInfo(title: String?, description: String?)

}

class DashboardCell: UITableViewCell{



let cellInformationDelegate: cellInfoDelegate!

@IBOutlet weak var cellTitle: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var cellDescription: UITextField!

func setDashboardCell (cell: Dashboard) {
    cellTitle.text = cell.title
    cellDescription.text = cell.desccription
}

@IBAction func cellTitleEdited(_ sender: Any) {

    if cellDescription.text != "" && cellTitle.text != "" {
cellInformationDelegate.tableCellInfo(title: (cellTitle.text)!, description: (cellDescription.text)!)
}

    if cellTitle.text != "" {
        cellInformationDelegate.tableCellInfo(title: (cellTitle.text)!, description: nil)
    }

}
@IBAction func cellDescriptionEdited(_ sender: Any) {

    if cellDescription.text != "" && cellTitle.text != "" {
        cellInformationDelegate.tableCellInfo(title: (cellTitle.text)!, description: (cellDescription.text)!)
    }

    if cellDescription.text != ""  {
        cellInformationDelegate.tableCellInfo(title: nil, description: (cellDescription.text)!)
    }

}



required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}



}
```

Dashboard -------------------------------------------------------

```
//
//  Dashboard.swift
//  Pursuit 1.0
//
//  Created by Ryan Du on 9/27/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Ryan Du. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
class Dashboard {
    var title: String
    var desccription: String
    init(title: String, description: String){
        self.title = title
        self.desccription = description
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `createArray`?

Comment: I used to call 'createArray' when I was still trying another way to get this to work which did not work and i frogot to delete that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than registering the cell reload the tableview.

```
@IBAction func dashboardAddA(_ sender: Any) {

    events.append(Dashboard(title: "Untitled", description: "Add A Description Here"))
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

or insert the row with an animation

```
@IBAction func dashboardAddA(_ sender: Any) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: events.count, section: 0)  
    events.append(Dashboard(title: "Untitled", description: "Add A Description Here"))
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

Please name methods with starting lowercase letter according to the naming convention